# How to re-map the shortcut to remove a node connection (cutting tool)?

Tags: node-editor, workflow, shortcut, operator

I use a graphics tablet because using a mouse starts to hurt my wrist. I need to either find the NAME of the "slashing" disconnect function between nodes that works identically like in Houdini FX (the name for the keybind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>RMB</kbd>, the wrangler doesn't list it, at least to my eyes across 2 days in the list), or I need to make a custom keybind of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> because it's a dup for box select.

In the documentation in the blender addon, it says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> is lazy connect, but it's showing me a cut tool icon, so that doesn't seem right at all... The documentation for it on the online Blender site is WRONG. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> is the cutter tool, not Lazy Connect. Lazy Connect in the Addon keybind list is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I don't want to wear out my right mouse button on my graphics pen!

Comment: You'd like to re-map the cutting tool to basically remove the connection right? If so, it's a built-in key and has nothing to do with node wrangler. Go to *Keymap > Node Editor Global > Cut Links*. Set the map type to keyboard and its type to Y. Does that help?

Comment: Tyvm, no one on the Blender discord wanted to hep meh.  You have no idea how much this lowers my stress.  It's beautiful!

Comment: Weird, at the time I couldn't upvote the answer to see the note that said click the check mark.  Now I could and did.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*That's a built-in key and has nothing to do with Node Wrangler.*

Go to *Keymap > Node Editor Global > Cut Links* and change it to whatever you like:

[image]

To get a Houdini like key binding, set its 'map type' to 'keyboard' and its type to <kbd>Y</kbd>.